# How to chain multiple "or" or "and" statements in ramda and preserve short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: javascript, filter, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to filter an array of posts against a user defined text. Each post has an `id` and a `text` property which should be searched. If the search-text is an empty string all posts should obviously be displayed - no need to check if the other predicates resolve to true. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```js
const hasText = R.curry((text, post) => R.reduce(R.or, false, [
    R.equals("", text),
    R.includes(text, post.text),
    R.includes(text, post.id.toString())
]))

const posts = [{id: 1, text: "a"},{id: 2, text: "b"},{id: 3, text: "c"}]

console.log(R.filter(hasText("b"), posts));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

The problem here is that all of the predicates are evaluated upfront even though that is unneccessary.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect as using plain `||` in a more functional way using ramda?

Comment: You might be looking for [`anyPass`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#anyPass) (or [`any`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#any))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is an empty string, you don't need to filter the array at all. To check if any of the predicates is truthy, you can use R.any:

```js
const { curry, pipe, prop, toString, includes, filter, anyPass, isEmpty } = R

// check if prop includes text
const propIncludes = curry((key, text) => pipe(prop(key), toString, includes(text)))

// filter an array of posts, and check if any of the prop contains the text
const hasText = curry((text, posts) => filter(anyPass([
  propIncludes('text', text),
  propIncludes('id', text),
]))(posts))

// skips filtering if text is empty
const checkText = curry((text, posts) => isEmpty(text) ? posts : hasText(text, posts))

const posts = [{id: 1, text: "a"},{id: 2, text: "b"},{id: 3, text: "c"}]

const result = checkText('b', posts)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This certainly works but it sure seems like a lot of exta work considering that it basically achieves the same as: `text === '' ? posts : posts.filter(p => ~p.text.indexOf(text) || ~p.id.toString().indexOf(text))`. I begin to wonder if ramda is really the way forward for me :(

Comment: @subarachnid: I believe you're viewing Ramda wrong (note: I'm one  of Ramda's main authors.)  Ramda is not a framework you should use to do all tasks.  It's a library that makes a certain style of coding easier to do in JS.  Use it when it makes your code simpler, more performant, or easier to maintain.  Don't use it when it doesn't do so.

Comment: And what happens when you want to search more than just the 'text' and 'id' properties? How does your "simplier" expression need to change to accommodate the new requirements, vs the answers given here? What if you want to do more than just substring matching? By thinking about and building composable functions you can adapt or reuse your code more easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `R.propSatisfies` function in a manner similar to the other answer's `propIncludes` function:

```js
const textContains = curry(
  (srch, value) => pipe(toString, includes(srch))(value)
)

const postHasText = curry(
  (text, post) => anyPass([
        propSatisfies(textContains(text), 'text'),
        propSatisfies(textContains(text), 'id')
  ])(post)
)

const postsWithText = curry(
  (text, posts) => filter(postHasText(text), posts)
)
```

Alternatively, as shown in the example below, you can make an intermediate helper method `propsContain` and then `postHasText` is a bit simpler, and you can reuse the `propsContain` for other things too.

```js
const { curry, pipe, toString, props, includes, filter, any, isEmpty } = R

const textContains = curry(
  (srch, value) => pipe(toString, includes(srch))(value)
)

const propsContain = curry(
  (srch, propList, entity) => pipe(props(propList), any(textContains(srch)))(entity)
)

const postHasText = propsContain(R.__, ['id', 'text'], R.__)

const searchPosts = curry(
  (qry, posts) => isEmpty(qry) ? posts : filter(postHasText(qry), posts)
)

const posts = [{id: "a", text: "foo"},{id: 2, text: "box"},{id: 3, text: "bat"}]
const results = searchPosts('a', posts)
console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```